# Run a Loop number of rows time present in webpage in selenium basic

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape data from website on bases of product name. There are different rows in web table for a unique product. Some have single row from which I have to grab data, some have two rows and some contain multiple rows.
What I want to do is count the number of rows of that product, and then want to run Loop as much times as rows of the product.
Xpath for that matching rows is

```
//td[contains(., 'Product Name') /parent::tr
```

This xpath gives the all rows on which I have to work further. I am using Chrome browser for automation.

Any suggestion and help is much needed and warmly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Excel VBA sir...

Comment: What URL are you using?...